# Rectangle / Bounding Box Collision slightly off?

Tags: collision, rectangles, bounding-box

I have some LUA code that calls a function that returns true if the player collides with a rectangle. I'm pretty sure the math is correct and it does actually work most of the time, but for some reason sometimes it will randomly return true if there isn't a collision, when the player is moving around. Usually this occurs when a rect is close to the player but still not touching. The weird thing is that it only happens from time to time.

Is the math 100% correct for two rectangles to collide? Keep in mind the origin of player_x, player_y, rect_x, rect_y are all centered, hence the recurring "/2" in the code.

```
function hasCollided(player_x, player_y, player_width, player_height, rect_x, rect_y, rect_width, rect_height)
if math.abs(rect_x - player_x) <= rect_width / 2 + player_width / 2 and math.abs(rect_y - player_y) <= rect_height / 2 + player_height / 2 then 
return true
else
return false
end
```